# SQL: How to select single rows position

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, select

Let's say I have a table that has 3 fields: (`id, name, points`).

Now initially I want to order them by points and also get the position. So here's my current query that does this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    points,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS position
FROM
    mytable;
```

This now works, and I get the following result set:

[image]

Here's where it gets tricky. Let's say I'm interested in specific row. For example I am interested in `EnglishRose`. I would love to know what position it has based on the points.

I can't just return the whole set and then iterate until I find this row because this table is massive (let's say we are talking about 100,000+ records. I am trying to find most optimal solution for this. Any ideas? Keep in mind any solution that is working should hopefully also be optimal. I am asking because probably some non optimal sub selects can be done

Any ideas by MySQL experts? Btw my mysql version is `>8`

Comment: Use a Materialized View (if your DB supports it) - or if not even just a normal `VIEW` but with judicious use of `INDEX` on your base-table should give you more than adequate performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CTE : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

They allow you to treat a query as a local table.

You could do something like

```
WITH
localPositionning AS (
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  points,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS position
FROM
  mytable
  )
SELECT * FROM localPositionning WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The records will not all be scanned, but only the ones with points that are higher than the one you're looking for:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS position
  from mytable
  where points >= (
    select points
    from mytable
    where name = 'b'
  )
)
select max(position) as position from CTE;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RaE7smF1)

Answer (score -2):

If you know the specific element by name that you want to isolate you can use the WHERE statement like so:

WHERE (name = 'EnglishRose')

(Im not to sure if this is 100% correct since its been a while since i wrote SQL :-))

I hope this helps!

Comment: This should not be correct, since WHERE clause will make it so the position in the SQL statement I provided will be 1. I need to maintain the same position as in the full query

Comment: Have you tried a subquery? like so: SELECT
    id,
    name,
    points,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE points > t.points) + 1 AS position
FROM
    mytable t
WHERE
    name = 'EnglishRose';